# Why does method 'readdirSync' use so much memory when reading directory with big amount of files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is an example of NodeJS code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function toMb (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

console.log('Memory usage before "readdirSync" apply: ', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

fs.readdirSync('./parseLogFiles/reports');

console.log('Memory usage after "readdirSync" apply: ', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
```

Directory "reports" contains 300.000 files.

I have got the following results:

```
Memory usage before "readdirSync" apply:  2.01 MB
Memory usage after "readdirSync" apply:  22.38 MB
```

Why memory using increased more than 10 time (2.01 vs 22.38)?

For "readdir" i have the same results.

Another example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function toMb (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

console.log('Memory usage before "readdirSync" apply: ', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

var filesList = fs.readdirSync('./parseLogFiles/reports');

console.log('Memory usage after "readdirSync" apply: ', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
console.log('Files list size: ', toMb(Buffer.byteLength(filesList.join(''))) + ' MB');
```

I have got the following results:

```
Memory usage before "readdirSync" apply:  2.01 MB
Memory usage after "readdirSync" apply:  22.38 MB
Files list size:  11.13 MB
```

From where come 9,24Mb (22.38 - 11.13 - 2.01) from?

Comment: Try exposing the garbage collector (`node --expose_gc`) and call `global.gc()` after the `fs.readdirSync()` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @robertklep. Thanks for your reply. Yes, global.gc() cleared the memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the way the readdir is implemented...

It has to load all 300k files in that directory into memory to give you the list. 300k filenames actually take up a lot of space = )

It is implemented on top of the C scandir method, which does dynamic memory allocation and grows memory usage incrementally based on the number of items...so as it reads items in the dir it will continually resize (increase) the memory needed to hold the list of items.